# Outside where clause in a mysql subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this mysql query:

```
(select orderID,orderNumber,locked,complete from 
orders where orderType='order' order by orderID desc limit 4) order by orderID asc
```

This gives the last 4 orders in the table and then sorts them in ascending order. I wanted to add a where clause in this so that once I get the last 4 records I only want the records which has the complete value set to `false`

So if the query returned 4 rows with one complete set to true the final query only returns 3 .

I thought I could do something like this:

```
(select orderID,orderNumber,locked,complete from 
orders where orderType='order' order by orderID desc limit 4) order by orderID asc
where complete is false
```

This give me error on

> where complete is false' at line 3

I also tried to make it a subquery which gives me the same error:

```
select sub1.orderID,sub1.orderNumber,sub1.locked,sub1.complete
from(
(select orderID,orderNumber,locked,complete from orders where orderType='order' order by orderID desc limit 4) 
 order by orderID asc) as sub2
 ) as sub1
 where sub1.complete is 0
```

Comment: where has to be before order.

Comment: Also you can't use `IS` with integer values, you must use it with `true`, `false` or `unknown`

Comment: @Nick, i tried using true/false in INT, its working fine. https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=PqFvfCQ7r9

Comment: It is a bollean field so I can either use  `=0` ,`is 0` or `is false`

Comment: @ϻᴇᴛᴀʟ yes, you can do `1 is true`, but you can't do `true is 1` which is what OP is doing in their second query

Comment: @jedu you can't do `boolean is int`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=aa422745b44eb245bab68e48b341612e https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is

Comment: If I put `where` before order it will give me last 4 orders which is not complete. What I want is any last 4 orders and then remove all of the complete ones from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most easily written using a derived table:

```
select *
from (select orderID,orderNumber,locked,complete 
      from orders 
      where orderType='order' 
      order by orderID desc limit 4) o
where complete is false
order by orderID asc
```

For a sample table:

```
create table orders (orderID int,
                     orderType varchar(20), 
                     orderNumber int,
                     locked tinyint(1),
                     complete tinyint(1));
insert into orders values
(1, 'order', 10, false, false),
(2, 'order', 20, true, false),
(3, 'order', 39, false, false),
(4, 'order', 41, true, false),
(5, 'return', 42, false, false),
(6,'order',  47, false, true),
(7, 'order', 50, true, false),
(8, 'order', 99, false, false);
```

This gives:

```
orderID     orderNumber     locked  complete
4           41              1       0
7           50              1       0
8           99              0       0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d762b377dd314de82c70fdfc230c913b)